# Grails 3 and Spring @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, grails-3.0

In Grails 3 I'm trying to use spring-security-oauth, which provides a few endpoints via the @RequestMapping I can see in the mbeans that the path is configured but any request always hits grails and returns a 404.

The requests never seem to hit any of the endpoints configured by the spring-security-oauth lib. Is there anyway to insure the requests hit the endpoints in the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the endpoints configured by @RequestMapping show in a Grails 3 app using Java config you have to use the following set up in Application.groovy

```
@ComponentScan("my.org.config")
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application)
    }
}
```

Do not use application.yml in the following way:

```
grails:
    profile: web
    spring:
        bean:
            packages:
                - my.org.config
```

While the beans will be picked up anything with @RequestMapping will not be accessible.