# spring boot RestController not seen from Grails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, spring-boot, grails-3.0

I have made a grails 3 application

```
$ grails create-app helloworld
```

Into this one I have created a spring controller DemoController.groovy

```
package helloworld
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
/**
 * A controller responding to
 * curl http://localhost:8080/demo
 * source location: src/main/groovy/helloworld/DemoController.groovy
 *
 */
@RestController
class DemoController {
  @RequestMapping("/demo")
  String demo() {
    "Hello demo!"
  }
}
```

Using

```
$spring run src/main/groovy/helloworld/DemoController.groovy &  
$curl http://localhost:8080/demo
```

*WORKS FINE*

Using

```
$gradle bootrun &  
$curl http://localhost:8080/demo
```

*FAILS!* Grails reports that `/demo` cannot be found

When I do the same thing from a clean spring boot application (made from http://start.spring.io/ ) it works fine

I cannot see what is wrong

Comment: you have to define your spring controller as bean. you could define it in `resources.groovy` beans closure (`demoController(DemoController)`) or add the controller package to `grails.spring.bean.packages` config property or annotate your `Application` class with `@ComponentScan`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution in ( [Grails 3 and Spring @RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736850/grails-3-and-spring-requestmapping) )

The Grails application must have a @ComponentScan to the package hierarchy of the Grails application java package. In this case it is "helloworld"

Application.groovy (generated by Grails) now looks like this:

```
@ComponentScan("helloworld")
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    GrailsApp.run(Application)
  }
}
```