# onStartup method of WebApplicationInitializer never gets called

Tags: spring, grails

I have a Grails application. I am trying to set an active Spring profile by using the `onStartup` method of `WebApplicationInitializer`.
I have annotated this Java class with `@Configuration` but `onStartup` method never gets invoked.

```
package my.package;

@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "test");
    }
}
```

In `Config.groovy` I have added,

```
grails.spring.bean.packages = ['my.package']
```

I also tried adding following code in resources.groovy

```
xmlns context: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
context."component-scan" "base-package": "my.package"
```

But whatever code changes I try `onStartup` method never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `application.yml` and it worked in `dev` environment but after packaging it into a war using `prod` profile, for some reason it stopped picking up my java config annotated with `@Configuration`.

The solution was to modify `Application.groovy` as recommended in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736850/grails-3-and-spring-requestmapping):

```
@ComponentScan("my.package")
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
...
}
```

Note: Overriding `packageNames()` in `Application.groovy` recommended in the docs also doesn't work.